# Going through Paris airport customs with 5 cell phones

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, electronic-items, air-france

My wife and I are traveling to India from California next month. On our way we are staying in Paris for a week. I bought 3 new cell phones for my family in India, so we are traveling with total 5 phones (3 new ones, in addition to the 2 we currently have).

I know how to deal with customs in India, but what should I expect at Paris airport? Has anybody done this before?

Answer (score 4):

If they are your property and you will not be leaving them in the EU (giving them away, selling them, etc.) then you should be fine.

It's possible that the border officer may question your purposes in France since you have so many phones, but if you have a reasonable explanation, you should be fine.  Just be honest.

Comment: Yes, I do not intend to leave them in France. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Do you have any sources for that? I know that some countries also care about what you transport through them (but I don't know any more specifics). Also, how do you prove that the goods will leave the country again?

Comment: It's impossible to document, really, except to share the experiences of others.  I have a lot of personal experience with border crossing (particularly Canada/US but have entered several countries in the EU too).  Each country will have an information page on what is allowed to be imported - France's is http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/your-stay-in-france-practical-information/article/customs-information ..  As for proving, that is hard to do and is largely up to the customs officer and whether he believes your story.  He may charge tax if he does not.